# how to make Search Program

Tags: vb.net

Do you have any tutorial how to make a search program in vb.net?
I am using dotNet2005 and MS-Access. As a newbie programmer, I know how to make a program that seeks with single filter, but like the picture below that seaches with many filter is out of my programming knowledge. Please give me some link... Thanks in advance :)

kindly check my previous posts to know my basic programming style...

[image]

Comment: could you give us the schema of your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of what exactly you're searching through, the basic setup will be the same.  However, if you're asking specifically concerning MS Access -- I'd start at MSDN.  But for a more general pattern:

1. Create or get some array or collection of the objects through which you wish to search (a directory, a csv file, a database).
2. Loop through each object, checking your conditions with either a single conditional IF statement or nested statements (that will depend on the complexity of the conditions and if there are prerequisites between the conditions).
3. Once found, exit the loop and return the found object -- or return false.

This would looks something like this (although this is not actual code):

```
Dim Objects() 'whatever you're searching through

Dim Found As Boolean = False
Dim FoundObj

While Found = False
    For Each Object in Objects
        If Condition1 And Condition2 And Condition3 Then
            Found = True
            FoundObj = Object
        End If                   
    Next
End While

If Found
    Return FoundObj
Else
    Return Nothing
End If
```